# Why Centos RPM can not be done by the root user

Tags: centos, root, rpm

[In CentOS wiki says](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetupRpmBuildEnvironment) that can not be done rpm-packages under the root user, because it may damage the system. Why? 
I do not understand what exactly it can do harm. The documentation RPM nothing found.
Thanks.

> Building RPMs should **NEVER** be done with the root user. It should **ALWAYS** be done with an unprivileged user. Building RPMs as root might damage your system. You have been warned.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I'd suggest that you [edit] the question to quote the specific sentence/paragraph that you want to understand.

Comment: Setting up the rpmbuild environment in /home/[name]/ : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/need-rpm-package-for-php-version-5-2-7-and-up-on-redhat-5-1-a-766486/#13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build an RPM you are effectively running "untrusted code".  The problem is that a badly written application might try to write content into system directories (e.g. `/bin` or `/usr/bin`) during the compile/build process.  This could just be due to buggy code or a mistake in the options passed.

If you are running as a non-root user then this will fail and your system is safe.  If you are running as root then you might end up overwriting code programs or libraries and break your system.

First rule of thumb for Unix sysadmin: don't do things as root unless you *have* to.  That way mistakes can't destroy the whole machine :-)